# Debugger executable '/usr/local/bin/gdb' is not signed. As a result, debugging may not work properly

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, gdb

Debugger executable `/usr/local/bin/gdb` is not signed. As a result, debugging may not work properly in vscode in macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

I am providing the launch.json file for reference.

---

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/ghermite.mod",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gdb",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "externalConsole": false,
        "preLaunchTask": "build"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.owsiak.org/running-gdb-in-macos-sierra/

Comment: @VladimirF I am trying to debug a fortran90 code in vscode and it throws the message “Debugger executable ‘/usr/local/bin/gdb/' is not signed. As a result debugger may not work properly.” I can run the code perfectly but can not debug. Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html me.tioned in the above link by Oo.oO

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: No, it was not clear dear doranm09. Please do not use deleted messages to send undeletable messages to 10k users. That is clear abuse, especially if the said messages contain personal attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to get around it by installing the [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) extension.

Comment: It would be also beneficial to mention that you need to change debug type to `lldb` and adjust other launch parameters according to CodeLLDB's docs...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, MacOS has some policies for the debuggers. However I still couldn't get gdb extensions to run  properly even after running steps from: https://www.owsiak.org/running-gdb-in-macos-sierra/ (even though `gdb` itself seems to be starting).

What solved the issue for me was to change debugger extension to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb

After installing this extension you need to change debug type from `cppdbg` to `lldb` and adjust other settings to match the ones from CodeLLDB's docs: https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/blob/v1.10.0/MANUAL.md

For me it was renaming `stopAtEntry` to `stopOnEntry`

After performing those steps C++ apps should be debugged just like you'd expect them to be.